# PHP - Adding a string to an array of query rows

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know much about PHP, i'm not even sure if the question makes much sense but i'm trying to print the values of an array i have created. Here's the array:

```
    $resultJogadorInfo = array("sucesso" => "1",
                               "id" => $resJogadorInfo["id"],
                               "username" => $resJogadorInfo["username"],
                               "nome" => $resJogadorInfo["nome"],
                               "apelido" => $resJogadorInfo["apelido"],
                               "email" => $resJogadorInfo["email"]);
```

All the values except for "sucesso" are results of an sql query and are fetched using `mysqli_fetch_array`. 
I can echo each individual value except for "sucesso" which gives an "Undefined index: sucesso".

The code use to print out values is:

```
echo $resJogadorInfo["sucesso"]; 
echo $resJogadorInfo["id"]; 
echo $resJogadorInfo["username"]; 
echo $resJogadorInfo["nome"]; 
echo $resJogadorInfo["apelido"]; 
echo $resJogadorInfo["email"];
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the code which you are using to print the array values

Comment: Array which you have mentioned `$resultJogadorInfo`, and the array which you are using to print `$resJogadorInfo` are different arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the original array which was returned from database:

```
echo $resJogadorInfo["sucesso"];
```

Replace that with the array you created:

```
echo $resultJogadorInfo["sucesso"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an extra value in the result set array, you could just add it into the SQL SELECT...

```
SELECT "1" as sucesso, id, username...
```

which may save you having to process the array afterwards.